# What is the correct ordering for a multi-key sort?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of Python objects with two attributes:  age and height.  I want to sort the objects and I want age to be the primary key in the sense that I will compare two objects' ages and only use height as a tie breaker.

I understand that Python's sort is stable so it's feasible to get the desired effect by first sorting the list by one key and then sorting it again using the other.  I can't figure out,
though, in which order the two keys should be individually sorted.  Could someone please tell me the correct order and also help me understand why sort stability allows this kind of decomposition?  Thanks.

Comment: The last sort is "the most important one". So if you implement something like this with a series of consecutive sorts, you do them based on the least "important" attribute first, and the most "important" attribute last. However, there's a better way: use a comparator that considers both the ages and the height.

Comment: If you tried both of them knowing that one was correct, you would find out immediately.

Comment: You don't need multiple sorts. Just do one sort using a composite key, consisting of the most to least significant keys left to right.

Comment: Sort based on a tuple of age and height

Comment: " I can't figure out, though, in which order the two keys should be individually sorted." - I mean, there are exactly two possibilities. If you really don't understand the logic, why not just **try both and see which one gives the right answer**? "and also help me understand why sort stability allows this kind of decomposition?" - if you actually understand what it means for a sort to be stable, I don't understand how there can be any further confusion. Just try reasoning it out, by manually sorting a list of values, and making sure you implement a stable algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander, that's exactly what I was looking for.   The reason for asking this, rather than using a composite comparator, is eliminating the need to code the comparator.

Comment: @MarkLavin can you clarify your requirements? Why are you trying to eliminate the (explicit) comparator? This is precisely the kind of thing it exists for.

Comment: In my experience, a composite comparator requires using "key = cmp_to_key(...)" and then the comparator method itself, which usually takes 6-7 lines of code, so I'm just trying to save some paper.